# jQuery Get Current Index in class Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the current index on this code.

```
$('#smProductWishlist').on('keyup blur keypress', '.smqty', function(e){
                console.log( $(this).index() );
              });
```

It doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Current index means ??

Comment: What is the "current index"?

Comment: query by id returns only one element.

Comment: ` $(this)` is there a way to get the current index?

Comment: Index of what collection? What is shown gets index within siblings but you haven't shown a [mcve] or explained what is expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An item's index depends on what selector you use.  For example, an `li` with class `list-item` may be the fifth `li` but the first `list-item`.  Assuming, for example, you're looking for index relative to class:

```
<input type="text" class="smqty" placeholder="one" />
<input type="text" id="smProductWishlist" class="smqty" placeholder="two" />
<input type="text" class="smqty" placeholder="three" />
<input type="text" class="smqty" placeholder="four" />
<input type="text" class="smqty" placeholder="five" />

<script>
  $('#smProductWishlist').on('keyup blur keypress', function(e){
    console.log( $('.smqty').index(this) );
  });
<script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this code with Html as well?

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm...

Comment: @Amit thanks for the recommendation, adding the HTML helped clarify the answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

`a.index(b)` returns the index of b in the list a:

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
  <li id="baz">baz</li>
</ul>
```

```
var $elements = $("li")
$elements.on("click", function(e) {
    console.log( $elements.index($(this)) )
})
```